# Show results containing a sentence typed in the textbox

Tags: php, jquery

Hello I want to make a textbox that can select data from a table, when input is givin to the textbox it should autocomplete the sentance with any words it matches within the

I already have this piece of code and it works but it only shows result of the first symbol you type in.

```
function lookup(inputString)
{
    if(inputString.length == 0)
    {
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    }    
    else     
    {    
        $.post("sql_naam_klant.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data)    
        {   
    if(data.length >0)    
    {    
        $('#suggestions').show();    
        $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
    }
        });
    }
}

function fill(thisValue) 
{
    $('.inputString').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('.suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="naam_klant" size="20" id="naam_klant" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" >    
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
```

UPDATE:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root' ,'*', 'records');
if(!$db) 
{
// Show error if we cannot connect.        
echo 'ERROR: Could not connect to the database.';
} 

else 
{
// Is there a posted query string?
if(isset($_POST['queryString']))
{
$queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);
// Is the string length greater than 0?
if(strlen($queryString) >0) 
{
$query = $db->query("SELECT naam_klant FROM overboekingen WHERE naam_klant LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10");     

if($query)
{
while ($result = $query ->fetch_object())
{
echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$result->naam_klant.'\');">'.$result->naam_klant.'</li>';
}
}

else 
{
echo 'ERROR: There was a problem with the query.';
}
} 
else 
{
} // There is a queryString.
} 
else 
{
echo 'There should be no direct access to this naam_klant script!';
}   
}
?>
```

Comment: yeah you should use the %string% in your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer the question because it is incomplete. We need to see the content of the `sql_naam_klant.php` to see why is it like that.

I am assuming that the error is in the query.

Use the `Wildcard Symbol (%)` in your where statements.

```
"Select * from tblnames where name like '%$queryString%';"
```

Will edit this answer as soon as you provide us with complete details.

If you want to find what you typed inside,beginning or end of a text block use the wildcard in both start and end of the search keyword. `%$queryString%`. If what you are looking for is the in beginning of a block of text then use `$queryString%` and if you're looking at the end of a text blook `%$queryString`.

Comment: I updated the tread, also I tryed to use [a-z] so everything will be autocompleted as soon as you type a letter but it didnt worked. Basicly a wildcard is no option since I want it to autocomplete any given sentance in the 'comments' page wich can have allot of text.

Comment: Okay, so I have read your code and i don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: If you want to find what you typed inside of a block text use the wildcard in both start and end of the search keyword. %keyword%.

Comment: Thank you I got it to work, indeed the %keyword% did the trick !

Comment: Accept the answer then. So that others will know.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a .change() javascript event and do an async ajax post every time the input changes and update the suggestions div whenever the request is completed - that's how i would do it